# I can not login spark openfire from another machin which is on same wifi lan network

Tags: xmpp, wifi, chat, openfire

Hello I created openfire server into my machine also  setup spark into my machine.I created user in openfire and can login with username and password on same machine but not from another computer which is on same wifi network.

Comment: Please add the issue that you are facing ! in detail !

Answer (score 0):

That can be due to firewall. XMPP default port is 5222. Disable the firewall on Openfire machine or allow incoming connections to port 5222.